# Existence of global solution of $x''(t)=-x(t)^3+x'(t)+1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have found this problem in an examination paper, and I can't find a solution.

**Problem**: Consider the following ODE

$$x''(t)=-x(t)^3+x'(t)+1$$

Prove that, for any initial values $x(0)=x_0,x'(0)=y_0$, there exists a unique *global* solution $x(t;x_0,y_0)$ defined for every $t\in \mathbb{R}$.

One may reduce the problem to the first order autonomous system

$$\begin{cases}
x'(t)=y(t) \\
y'(t)=-x(t)^3+y(t)+1
\end{cases}
$$

defined by the $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^2)$ vector field $f(x,y)=(y,-x^3+y+1)$, which proves immediately that local solutions exist and are unique for any initial value $(x_0,y_0)$.

One can moreover sketch a phase portrait looking to the signs of $f$, finding that there is an (unstable) equilibrium point at $(1,0)$ and that the other trajectories are sort of spirals.

However, since neither $|f(x,y)|$ is bounded by a function linear in $|(x,y)|$ nor it is globally Lipschitz, the usual global existence theorems (that I'm aware of) cannot be applied.

Anyway, let $(T_-,T_+)$ be the maximal interval on which the solution is defined. I guess that one might prove quite easily that $T_-=-\infty$ since, reversing the time, the equilibrium point is asymptotically stable. Now suppose $T_+<+\infty$. Then we know (*) that the solution should be such that $\lim_{t\to T_+}|(x(t),y(t))|=+\infty$. However I cannot find any contradiction in order to show that this is not possible and hence $T_+=+\infty.$

Thus the question is: how can one show that actually $T_+=+\infty$?

(*) If $t_m$ is an increasing sequence such that $\lim_{m\to\infty}t_m=T_+$ and $\lim_{m\to\infty}(x(t_m),y(t_m))=(\xi,\eta)\in \mathbb{R}^2$, then the initial value problem with $x(T_+)=\xi$ and $y(T_+)=\eta$ would produce an extension of the original solution to the interval $(T_-,T_++\epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon$.

[image: Phase portrait]

Comment: Why don't you try doing $y'(t)=y(x)y'(x)$ in order to solve $y$ in terms of $x$?

Comment: I have already thought about it, but (1) $y$ cannot be expressed *globally* as a function of $x$ and (2) in any case knowing the $(x,y)$ equation of the trajectories would not give any information about the speed at which they are travelled.

Comment: this is at best a hint, but the time derivative of the function $h=x^4/4+y^2/2$ is (up to mistakes) $y^2+y\leq 2 h +1/4$, so $h$ at time $t$ is at most something like $c \exp(2t)$, which gives (for any fixed $t$) a compact subset of the plane, so the solution can be continued (or more intuitively, it never goes to infinity)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the kind of estimate I was looking for! It seems to me that the inequality holds for $y^2+y\leq \underline{4}h+1/4$, but apart from that I think this completely solves the problem. Thank you very much